# Querying for Disabled AD Users in PowerShell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

When running a query such as

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | select DistinguishedName, Enabled
```

the Enabled column has a lot of null values (I was expecting true or false only). Why is this?

Is there a better command to get the enabled/disabled status of user accounts?

This is on a 2008R2 domain.

Comment: Are you running this from an account that has the permissions to read these ADUser properties? Do you, perhaps, need to elevate the Powershell session? I ran this on my 7000+ account domain and all values were either true or false, no blanks.

Comment: I ran it from an elevated session (same credentials) and it worked. I just now realized that the only accounts that previously returned true or false were members of the domain admins group. Odd, but it must be related to the why of my question. Repost as an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running this from an account that has the permissions to read these ADUser properties? Do you, perhaps, need to elevate the Powershell session? I ran this on my 7000+ account domain and all values were either true or false, no blanks.